# Is there a native button group element?

Tags: android, button, android-button

I need a horizontal group of two buttons. It should be, or at least look, native as I want my app to look completely native. I'm after the same style as the button group of the google maps app:

[image: Google map app] [image: Google map main screen]

Does anybody know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

What makes you believe those buttons are native?  :)
Actually those controls are custom `RadioButtons` enclosed in a `RadioGroup`.

Regarding the native buttons... usually these buttons have a different look and feel on different Android versions. For example on Android 2.2 the predominant color is white/gray, on Android 4.0 is blue.

Comment: so if i use custom custom radiobuttons, how can i make look them different for each versions? like making them look native :)

Comment: Well, those buttons actually use a background image, right? (or maybe they actually are ImageButtons, doesn't matter) So, one of the solutions would be to have multiple versions of image buttons and when starting the application check the Android version. Depending on Android version select and put the appropriate background resource. This is an idea.   
  
But, my question is why would you do this? :)....

Comment: OK, thanks! :) 
Well, i'm working on an app which use native elements. it would probably look weird if just those buttons wouldn't look native.